# Can Sagnac effect be observed in coiled, rotating electrical cables conducting electric signals?

Tags: electric-fields, electricity, speed-of-light, fiber-optics

Can Sagnac effect be observed in coiled, rotating electrical cables conducting electric signals, in a similar way to that observed in coiled, rotating optical fibers? And if so then who demonstrated it  first in electric cables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was: yeah, you can have counterpropaging electic signals in a single cable, so I rather expected that in that type of setup a Sagnac effect can be elicited.

I have a point of concern though. In the case of a propagating electric signal: that propagation is not confined to the wire. Outside of the actual wire there is an electromagnetic field. You cannot **not** have that external electromagnetic effect.

In an optical Sagnac setup the propagation of the light is confined to a conduit. In the case of a fiber optic gyro there is the option to let light enter and exit the fiber with an fiber optic coupler. Other setups use the type of mirror that reflects a percentage of the light falling on it, and transmits the rest. With optics it is possible to achieve partial reflection without introducing unwanted phase effect.

It seems plausible to me that it is possible to elicit the Sagnac effect with radio waves. For instance, it seems plausible to me that three radio reflectors, arranged in a triangle, can serve as the reflectors for a Sagnac setup with radio waves.

A electromagnetic signal propagating along the length of a wire is a form of propagating electromagnetic wave. But compared to propagation in air it is a more complicated form. It could be that it will be hard to arrange entering and exiting the circuit in a way that does not introduce unwanted phase effects.

About electric wires and propagation of energy:
Youtube video by Derek Muller (follow-up to an earlier video)
[How electricity actually works](https://youtu.be/oI_X2cMHNe0)

Video, youtube channel: AlphaPhoenix
Response to the first Derek Muller video
[I bought 1000 meters of wire to settle a physics debate](https://youtu.be/2Vrhk5OjBP8)

Comment: A coaxial cable is a waveguide, similar to an optical fiber. The main difference is that it has a mode with a cutoff frequency of 0.

Comment: @Cleonis While I appreciate your effort, your answer is a supposition or assumption "My first thought was: yeah...", rather than a conclusive statement, and unfortunately youtube videos don't establish who was the first person to demonstrate this effect.

Comment: @Jimski As far as I am aware of the setup you are curious about has not been tried. There are multiple possible explanations for that. It could be the idea has never occurred to anyone. It could be the idea has occurred but that allocating resources to build it was not approved. It could be that it is actually impossible to elicit a Sagnac effect this way. I knew of course my reply is speculative. I opted to post it, even though speculative, because it might give you clues to follow up.

Comment: @Cleonis OK, now I understand what you meant. I accepted and upvoted your answer.